# Exporting Html Element with HighChart Js in a word file, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to export html element containing a high chart to a word file. This is the HTML Code:

```
    <div>
        <div id="exportContent">
            <h2> What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

            <div id="container3">Placeholder for chart</div>

            <br />
            Test
        </div>

        <button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');">Export as .doc</button>
        <br />
    </div>
```

When I click the button, it will call the Export2Doc() method in the javascript, and will export the texts and highcharts of the "exportContent" div. For this I have used the following javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {

        $('#container3').highcharts({

            title: {
                text: 'Client-Side Download Example'
            },

            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
            }]

        });


    });

    function Export2Doc(element, filename = '') {

        var preHtml = "<html><head><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
        var postHtml = "</body></html>";

        var svg = $('#container3').highcharts().getSVG();

        var imageD1 = document.createElement('img');

        imageD1.setAttribute("align", "middle");
        imageD1.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center");
        var width = parseInt(svg.match(/width="([0-9]+)"/)[1]), height = parseInt(svg.match(/height="([0-9]+)"/)[1]);

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        widthTemp = 500;  //500
        heightTemp = (height / width) * widthTemp;

        canvas.setAttribute('width', widthTemp);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', heightTemp);
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, widthTemp, heightTemp);


        var image = "";
        if (canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')) {

            canvg(canvas, svg, {
                ignoreDimensions: true,
                scaleWidth: widthTemp,
                scaleHeight: heightTemp
            });

            image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }

        imageD1.src = image;

        var doc2 = document.createElement("div");
        doc2.appendChild(imageD1);
        var html = preHtml + document.getElementById(element).innerHTML + "<br>"+ doc2.innerHTML + postHtml;

        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
            type: 'application/msword'
        });

        var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);


        filename = filename ? filename + '.doc' : 'document.doc';


        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {

            downloadLink.href = url;
            downloadLink.download = filename;
            downloadLink.click();
        }

        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }

</script>
```

But when I export the elements of the "exportContent" div, only the texts are exported . The highchart is not exported. Though before exporting the highchart into the word file I have convert the highchart into svg format, but still it is not working

Comment: Could you post a sample jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: You cannot just export the image and paste it to your word file?